# create matrix function of vector input variable (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, anonymous-function, matrix-multiplication

I'm having trouble creating a function that does what I want.  I'm trying to create an anonymous function that, on accepting a vector of length N produces an NxN matrix.  I'd like to populate each element of the matrix (ie, with a loop).  A short example to be more specific:

```
N = 2;
Qjk = @(x,y) x * y;

for j = 1:N
  for k = 1:N

     Q(j,k) =@(x) Qjk(x(k),rand);

  end
end
```

In the end this should produce, eg.:

```
Q = @(x) [.23*x(1), .16*x(2); .95*x(1), .62*x(2)]
```

I can write the final expression above by hand and it works as required, but I'm unable to automate this process with a loop/vectorization.  Thanks.

Comment: Anybody else have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is my understanding that you want to create a `N x N` matrix of elements where the input is a vector of length `N`?... and more specifically, you wish to take each element in the input vector `x` and generate a new `1 x N` vector where each element in `x` gets scaled by this new `1 x N` vector?

You can avoid loops by using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
Q = bsxfun(@times, x(:).', rand(numel(x)));
```

I'm not sure what shape `x` is, whether it's a row or column vector but I'm not going to make any assumptions.  `x(:).'` will ensure that your vector becomes a row vector.  However, if you want to get your code working as it, get rid of the anonymous function declaration within the actual loop itself.  Also, you'll probably want to call `Qjk` as that is the function you declared, not `Q` as that is the matrix you are trying to populate.

Simply do:

```
N = 2;
Q = zeros(N); % New - Allocate to be more efficient
Qjk = @(x,y) x * y;

for j = 1:N
  for k = 1:N

     Q(j,k) = Qjk(x(k),rand); % Change

  end
end
```

Comment: What I have above yes once I removed the anonymous function calls. I just populated the matrices directly.  Can you not just use `bsxfun`? It does what you want and you can even wrap that into an anonymous function if you wish. `Q  = @(x) bsxfun(@times, x(:).', rand(numel(x)));`.

Comment: Hi Ray,  actually these solutions don't do what I want - I'd like the result to be an anonymous function of `x`.  Both of these appear to require me to define `x` first.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This: `Q = @(x) bsxfun(@times, x(:).', rand(numel(x)));` does not require you to define `x` first.  It is simply the same code I wrote above but wrapped in an anonymous function. Therefore you can just put in a vector and it'll output a `N x N` matrix for you.

Comment: That's true.  I know there's a lot of bsxfun love here, but is there a way to do this with for loops?  I'm handing this code off, and I think others find for loops more readable (for better or worse).

Comment: You can't write loops in an anonymous function... at least not natively.... you have to abuse `eval` if you want to do that.  One of the best ways to do what you're asking is to use `bsxfun`.  However, let me try and understand what you are doing in your other code first... are you trying to make a matrix of anonymous functions?... you can only use cell arrays for that.

Comment: Pretty good solution.  I'm interested in directly calling Qjk(x,y) and inheriting the `x` dependence in `Q`, but this will work in a pinch.  Consider removing the for loop code - it doesn't work on my machine after a `clear all`.

Comment: Hm.  I still get the error: `Reference to a cleared variable x.` :/